# Have one NodeJS program handle code for another program

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm developing a program, and I have a setTimeout that has to be available 24/7. But, the program sometimes goes up and down, and sometimes I have to shut it off to update it. So, the setTimeout gets shut off. Is there a way that I can get something like this

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    member.roles.remove(mutedRole); // remove the role
}, mutedTime);
```

be handled by another NodeJS app? Like, say one program is running, and it can tell another one to run this. Is this possible?

Just to clarify, I want to know if I can get one NodeJS program to run code for another program.

Comment: wrap it with try/catch ?

Comment: I've already done that before. That code works fine. I just want to know if what i'm asking is possible.

Comment: Discord provides a REST Api, you are just using the js library. You can do this in basically any language

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I shouldn't have mentioned discord.js. I'm just talking about NodeJS in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most you could do is to `exec`/`kill` another nodejs process from within your existing process, but I don't believe it's possible to control what the child process is actually doing.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

But from your usecase, it seems like what you actually need is some sort of CI/CD setup. Lookup gitlab pipelines.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/